# AJAX POST not functioning with jQuery 1.9.0 or greater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here is my following code for using AJAX calling a static webmethod on ASPX side. It used to work with **jQuery 1.2.0** , but I needed to update my **jQuery 2.1.1** and now ajax code doesn't even execute as it the code never falls under 'Failure' section

Can somebody nudge me in the right direction please? I have a feeling that I maybe skipping over a reference with the newer version of jQuery?

```
            <%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Ajax" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="../Design/jQueryCSS/bootstrap-select.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Design/scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="../Design/scripts/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Design/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="../Design/jQueryCSS/bootstrap.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Design/scripts/jquery.columnfilters.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Design/scripts/ToolBox.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var rtID = $('#<%=ddlRequestType.ClientID%>');
        //console.log(rtID[0].value);
        var temp = searchFields(rtID[0].value);
        console.log(temp);

        });

    function searchFields(rtID) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Reports.aspx/Search",
            data: JSON.stringify({requestTypeID: rtID}),
            //data: 'requestTypeID: "' + rtID + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                /*if (response.d == true) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }*/
                alert("hi");
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            }
        });
 </script>
```

Error:

[image]

And Yes I did validate `requestTypeID` value :-)

Comment: Try to investigate the server error.

Comment: Please check the networks tab in chrome and view the details of that error response...

Answer (score 1):

Try to send a JSON object instead of a String:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Reports.aspx/Search",
        data: {requestTypeID: rtID}, //Here
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            /*if (response.d == true) {
                console.log(response.data);
            }*/
            alert("hi");
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Afraid that didn't work either. Same issue of 500 (internal service error)

Comment: You should try to find out the error that the server return to the browser because a 500 internal error mean an error from the server. Something crashed in your .Net code.

Comment: Granted that there could be an error on the .NET side , however even if there is a crash , shouldn't $.ajax code fall under the 'failure' section?

Comment: Failure on ajax will only occur if the ajax call fails not the backend request. You can call a function that returns something but may fail (500 error), which is a success as far as the ajax request is concerned. Depends on what the ajax request is expecting in return.

Comment: Thanks @haxtbh , possible rootcause is that my web service is returning a `DataTable` where as **json** needs to get serialiazed data structure